How can I disable all index on a database that hasn't been restored yet?
I'm having to import a very large postgres database that I only have a pg_dump file for.  The dump is 5.5Tb in size.  I've seen many mentions to disable indexes and then re-index after the import to help speed up the import.  If I don't know what indexes will even exist, how can I go about disabling indexes before starting the pg_restore?
Postgres Version 15.7
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Any other suggestions on importing such a large database?


Add to question text Postgres version. 2) Read the docs pg_restore in particular the --section portion.


Thanks @AdrianKlaver.  Postgres newb so trying to understand.  If I specify pre-data, then data, and only do post-data aftet all that is done, would that be equivalent to not adding the indexes (or disabling and then re-indexing) until the data is all imported?


Yes. To test/verify you  could try on a dev database using the -t some_table option to pg_restore to work with only one table that you know has indexes on it.  2) I would read through the pg_restore link several times, there is a lot of helpful information there.


I should added the table you select should not have dependencies e.g. be child table in Foreign Key relationship as when you get to the post data section it will fail. This the long way of saying -t does not pull in table dependencies.

So running the pre-data and now the data section, I stated the restore with 24 jobs (28 cores, 56 threads on this server) and now I noticed that in pg_activity I have 23 jobs in an idle state (all running COPY commands) and only one job that's active.  This seems to have slowed down the import to a crawl, what would cause all those jobs to go idle?  The database is on local nvme drives, it's a bare metal server and this is the only thing on this server.


To your question add the complete pg_restore command. 2) Did you test with a smaller data set first? 3) What does the Postgres log show?


Thanks.

pg_restore --no-privileges --no-owner --section=data -d mainnet2 -j 24 external_node_latest.pgdump Is the full command.
Yes, I tested on one table and it worked fine.
Log output: 2024-06-29 16:43:00.775 UTC [39000] LOG:  checkpoint starting: wal 2024-06-29 16:44:11.890 UTC [39000] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 71354 buffers (27.2%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 33 recycled; write=70.557 s, sync=0.530 s, total=71.116 s; sync files=15, longest=0.17 3 s, average=0.036 s; distance=540696 kB, estimate=541039 kB


What does the Postgres log show?

Sorry, added log output.  Lots of checkpoint start/checkpoint complete logs

Does the log show any warnings?

No warnings and no errors.


Restore just the schema, nothing else
Remove the indexes from your fresh schema
Restore just the data

Order pizza and cola, watch TV, done.
Create indexes? If needed.

If you are restoring into an empty database, then there are no indexes to start with, apart from the system tables.
pg_dump outputs the index creation commands after the \copy commands, you don't need to do anything special to make that happen.
